# php weird bug where an array is not an array

Tags: php, arrays

I've been going mad trying to figure out why an array would not be an array in php.

For a reason I can't understand I have a bug in a smarty class. The code is this :

```
$compiled_tags = array();
for ($i = 0, $for_max = count($template_tags); $i < $for_max; $i++) {
   $this->_current_line_no += substr_count($text_blocks[$i], "\n");

   // I tried array push instead to see
   // bug is here
   array_push($compiled_tags,$this->_compile_tag($template_tags[$i]));
   //$compiled_tags[] = $this->_compile_tag($template_tags[$i]);

   $this->_current_line_no += substr_count($template_tags[$i], "\n");
```

}

the error message is

> Warning: array_push() expects
>   parameter 1 to be array, integer given
>   in ....

OR before with `[]`

> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as
>   an array in ....

I trying a var_debug on $compiled_tags and as soon I enter the for loop is not an array anymore but an integer. I tried renaming the variable, but same problem.

I'm sure is something simple that I missed but I can't figure it out. Any help is (as always) welcomed !

Comment: I'm not sure if this problem can be answered with the give info. Could you try adding more context?

Comment: It's a bug so weird that I can't begin to find a reson why this occured, but after a reboot it disapear. Probably should have try that sooner..

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$compiled_tags` is getting overwritten by something, probably the method call.

Try adding `print_r($compiled_tags);` between each line and then see where it changes from an empty array to a scalar. I would bet it happens after the method call `$this->_compile_tag()`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, `$compiled_tags[]` will ALWAYS work.  There may be a problem somewhere else in your code.  Maybe `_compile_tag()` uses `$compiled_tags` as a `global`?

Comment: that's what i though too. but i search into my entire project and no result. I'm starting to think i just need to reboot my computer :-)

Comment: I recommend commenting-out one piece of code at a time.  Remove $this->compile_tag() and replace it with "test"

Comment: I kind of find the answer after rebooting my computer, the problem didn't occur anymore.

Answer (score 0):

What's the scope of $compiled_tags?

It looks like the method _compile_tag(...) may be setting it to an integer.